# JavaFX: get ComboBox of ComboBoxTableCell

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to add a handler to the `ComboBox` inside a `ComboBoxTableCell` in a `TableView` in JavaFX8. I can see that there is a private `ComboBox` value in the `ComboBoxTableCell` class, yet I have no idea how to access it. I tell the column to use a `ComboBoxTableCell` via the `setCellFactory` method. Is there any way to get the `ComboBox`?

EDIT: I want to add a listener to the `ComboBox` which enables choosing items by entering keys. I already have one for a normal `ComboBox`and I would like to reuse the same for the `ComboBox` in the `TableCell`.

Comment: Why do you want to access the `ComboBox`. There is probably a better way of doing this...

Comment: updated the description

Comment: an implementation-dependent (don't - the risk is that it stops working as the implementation can change without notice!) way to access the combo the fact that the combo is set as graphic of the cell. The brittle approach is to listen to the graphic property of the cell until it changes from null to the combo, remove that listener, grab the new value (== combo) and do with it whatever you want. The clean way is to write your own comboBoxXXCell, c&p and modify (it's open source)

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there's no way to get the reference to the `ComboBox` of the `ComboBoxTableCell`. If that's true, it's not possible to add a listener to it.

An alternate approach would be to create your own custom cell containing a `ComboBox`. With this approach, you can manipulate the `ComboBox` in any way you'd like.

```
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxTable extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        int numOfCols = 2;

        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Generate dummy data.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++)
                row.add("Row" + i + "Col" + j);

            tableData.add(row);
        }

        TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();

        // Add columns to the table.
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCols; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            // The fourth argument in the method, the BiConsumer, might require
            // an explanation. Basically we are saying that when the BiConsumer
            // are given an ObservableList<String> and a String, we set the
            // value of the String as the value of the element at position "j"
            // of the row, where "j" will be the column index.
            table.getColumns().add(addComboBoxColumn(i, "Column " + i, row -> new SimpleStringProperty(row.get(j)),
                    (row, newText) -> row.set(j, newText)));
        }

        table.getItems().addAll(tableData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a TableColumn with ComboBoxCells.
     */
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> addComboBoxColumn(int index, String name,
            Function<ObservableList<String>, ObservableValue<String>> property,
            BiConsumer<ObservableList<String>, String> updater) {

        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(name);

        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(e -> new ComboBoxCell(updater, index));

        return col;
    }

    /**
     * A TableCell with a ComboBox in it.
     */
    public class ComboBoxCell extends TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String> {
        private ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();

        /**
         * @param updater
         *            The updater makes sure that the cell value corresponds
         *            with the value in the ComboBox.
         * @param colIndex
         *            The index of this column.
         */
        public ComboBoxCell(BiConsumer<ObservableList<String>, String> updater, int colIndex) {
            comboBox.setEditable(true);

            comboBox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((old, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (getIndex() >= 0) {
                    // We provide the BiConsumer.accept() with an
                    // ObservableList<String> and a String. The BiConsumer will
                    // do the operation specified in the definition we provided
                    // in addColumn() using these two objects.
                    updater.accept(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()), (String) newValue);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                // If we don't check if this value is the same as the old one,
                // the cursor is moved to the beginning of the editor every time
                // anything is typed.
                if (!item.equals(comboBox.getEditor().getText())) {
                    comboBox.getEditor().setText(item);
                }
                setGraphic(comboBox);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

an other possible solution is to add a StringConverter<>() to your ComboBoxTableCell<R, T>() for correct String display of an object and add a changeListener to your ObjectProperty

```
TableView<ParentObject> table = new TableView<>();

table.setEditable(true);

TableColumn<ParentObject, Item> col = new TableColumn<>("name");
       
col.setEditable(true);

col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {

    ObjectProperty prop = new SimpleObjectProperty<Item>(cellData.getValue().getItem());

    prop.addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        //do something for example set the Object in getValue()
        cellData.getValue().setItem(newVal);
    });

    return prop;

});
final StringConverter<Item> converter = new StringConverter<>() {

    @Override
    public Item fromString(final String string) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(final Item object) {
        return object.getLabel();
    }
};

// get your list of possible Objects to swap
List<Item> itemList = Database.getAllItems();

col.setCellFactory(c -> new ComboBoxTableCell(converter, FXCollections.observableArrayList(itemList)));

table.getColumns().add(col);
```

The Object SimpleObjectProperty<> can be replaced with other javafx.beans.properties for Example StringProperty, IntegerProperty, BooleanProperty or ListProperty

I'm aware that this isn't the 100% matching answer to the question but this helped me in my issue searching for the right answer to the problem

Comment: don't change the item nor any of its properties under-the-feet of the editing mechanism!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).